Application Insights telemetry returning CORS error in Quart
I have a backend developed using Quart that uses the quart_cors lib to avoid CORS problems. Everything was working fine, but when I try to add Application Insights from Microsoft Azure solutions the cors error returns.
This is the backend code:
app = cors(app, allow_origin="*", allow_headers=["Content-Type"])

Routes.py:
@app.before_request
    async def before_request():
        # Start tracing this request
        print("TEST")
        request.tracer = Tracer(exporter=AzureExporter(connection_string=os.getenv('CONNECTION_STRING_APPLICATION_INSIGHTS')), sampler=ProbabilitySampler(rate=1.0))
        request.tracer.span(name=request.path)

    @app.after_request
    async def after_request(response):
        # End tracing this request
        print("TEST 2")
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
        request.tracer.finish()
        
        return response

It returns like this on my react frontend application:


add app = cors(app, allow_origin="*", allow_headers=["Content-Type"], allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"])

response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
return response

@app.route('/your-endpoint', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'])
async def your_endpoint():
if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
# Handle preflight request
return '', 204
# Your endpoint logic here
return {'success': True}, 200


To address the CORS issue when integrating Application Insights into your Quart backend, ensure that the CORS settings are correctly configured.
Backend:
The backend code below logs application events by handling CORS, logging, and tracing.
python -m pip install opencensus-ext-azure quart quart-cors  

# Initialize the Quart app  
app = Quart(__name__)  
app = cors(app, allow_origin="*", allow_headers=["Content-Type"], allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"])  

# Set up tracing with Azure Application Insights  
def before_request():  
# Start tracing this request  
request.tracer = Tracer(exporter=AzureExporter('InstrumentationKey=YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY'), sampler=ProbabilitySampler(rate=1.0))  
request.span = request.tracer.span(name=request.path)  

def after_request(response):  
# End tracing this request  
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'  
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'  
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'  
request.span.finish()  
return response



  
# Define a sample route  
@app.route('/')  
async def index():  
logger.info('Processing index route')  
return {'message': 'Hello, World!'}

# Define another sample route  
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  
async def test():  
if request.method == 'POST':  
data = await request.json  
logger.info('Received POST data', extra={'custom_dimensions': {'data': data}})  
return {'message': 'Data received', 'data': data}  
return {'message': 'Test route'}

  

sample code :
import os
import logging
from quart import Quart, request, Response
from quart_cors import cors
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler  # Import AzureLogHandler
from opencensus.ext.azure.trace_exporter import AzureExporter
from opencensus.trace.samplers import ProbabilitySampler
from opencensus.trace.tracer import Tracer

# Initialize the Quart app
app = Quart(__name__)
app = cors(app, allow_origin="*", allow_headers=["Content-Type"], allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"])

# Set up logging to integrate with Azure Application Insights
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Set the log level to INFO or higher
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY'))

# Set up tracing with Azure Application Insights
def before_request():
    # Start tracing this request
    request.tracer = Tracer(exporter=AzureExporter(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY'), sampler=ProbabilitySampler(rate=1.0))
    request.span = request.tracer.span(name=request.path)

@app.after_request
async def after_request(response):
    # End tracing this request
    request.span.finish()
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    return response

# Handle OPTIONS requests
@app.route('/hello', methods=['OPTIONS'])
async def options():
    response = Response()
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    return response

# Define a sample route
@app.route('/')
async def index():
    logger.info('Processing index route')
    return {'message': 'Hello, World!'}

# Define another sample route
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
async def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = await request.json
        logger.info('Received POST data', extra={'custom_dimensions': {'data': data}})
        return {'message': 'Data received', 'data': data}
    return {'message': 'Test route'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.before_request(before_request)
    app.after_request(after_request)
    app.run()



Front end:
To integrate your Quart app with a React frontend, you need to set up your React app to make HTTP requests to the Quart backend. You need to make HTTP requests to your Quart backend. For this, you'll use the fetch API or a library like axios.
npm install axios  

The React frontend code below communicates with the backend, handling GET and POST requests.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';  
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {  
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');  
const [postData, setPostData] = useState({});  
const [testMessage, setTestMessage] = useState('');  
  
useEffect(() => {  
// Fetch data from the root endpoint  
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/')  
.then(response => {  
setMessage(response.data.message);  
})  
.catch(error => {  
console.error('There was an error fetching the data!', error);  
});  
}, []);  
  
const handlePostData = () => {  
const data = { key: 'value' }; // Example data to post  
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/test', data)  
.then(response => {  
setPostData(response.data);  
})  
.catch(error => {  
console.error('There was an error posting the data!', error);  
});  
};

useEffect(() => {  
// Fetch data from the test endpoint with GET request  
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/test')  
.then(response => {  
setTestMessage(response.data.message);  
})  
.catch(error => {  
console.error('There was an error fetching the test data!', error);  
});  
}, []);  
  
return (  
<div className="App">  
<h1>Fetch Data from Quart Backend</h1>  
<h2>Message from Root Endpoint:</h2>  
<p>{message}</p>  
  
<h2>Test GET Request:</h2>  
<p>{testMessage}</p>  
  
<h2>Test POST Request:</h2>  
<button onClick={handlePostData}>Send POST Request</button>  
<p>{postData.message}</p>  
<pre>{JSON.stringify(postData.data, null, 2)}</pre>  
</div>  
);  
}

export default App;




